# How to use the method for adding rows generated in context of typed data sets?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, strongly-typed-dataset

I've created a Winform Project and implemented an entity model framework.

I use two tables:

- `Münzen` with two columns `id` and `Münzwert`.
- `MünzenEinwerfen` with four columns `id`, `date`, `idMünzen` and `Anzahl`.

There is a relation between the column `id` of the table `Münzen` and column `idMünzen` of the table `MünzenEinwerfen`.

The data set generated automatically a method for adding rows:

```
public MünzenEinwerfenRow AddMünzenEinwerfenRow(System.DateTime Datum, MünzenRow parentMünzenRowByFK_MünzenEinwerfen_Münzen, int Anzahl)
{
    MünzenEinwerfenRow rowMünzenEinwerfenRow = ((MünzenEinwerfenRow)(this.NewRow()));
    object[] columnValuesArray = new object[]
    {
        null, Datum, null, Anzahl};
        if ((parentMünzenRowByFK_MünzenEinwerfen_Münzen != null))
        {
            columnValuesArray[2] = parentMünzenRowByFK_MünzenEinwerfen_Münzen[0];
        }
        rowMünzenEinwerfenRow.ItemArray = columnValuesArray;
        this.Rows.Add(rowMünzenEinwerfenRow);
        return rowMünzenEinwerfenRow;
    }
 }
```

I would like to use this method to add new records to the database via a ComboBox, but unfortunately I can't make this to work.

The problem is the second argument `MünzenRow parentMünzenRowByFK_MünzenEinwerfen_Münzen`. I can't create an object of `MünzenRow`, given the case this is necessary at all. I tried a lot of variants, but more in a try and error manner.

Comment: Pass `null` to second parameter if it is a `0/1-to-many` relationship. Otherwise you need a `Münzen` because it is a `1-to-many` relationship and `MünzenEinwerfen` requires a `Münzen` id.

Comment: I have no idea what the hell `Münzen` and `Einwerfen` means though so I can't help if you have a logical error in your model design.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mostruash . `Münzen` means coin, `MünzenEinwerfen` drop coins. I am working for a tracking programm for a piggy bank.

The `Münzen` Class does not have a `MünzenRow` field.

And there is a 1 to many relation.

I guess I need the row of the table `Münzen` for the selected item or value of the combo box...but I don't know how can I get this.

Comment: So there are coins and actions of them being dropped into the piggy bank? In that case doesn't `MünzenEinwefen` require a `Münzen` to exist so that you can actually drop it? I mean, why can't you create a `MünzenRow`?

Comment: Oh wait, I guess `MünzenRow` and `MünzenEinwefenRow` classes are ViewModel classes generated for you somehow, but I'm not familiar with WinForms project templates in Visual Studio.

Comment: I could create a MünzenRow like this:
`DataRowBuilder drb = new DataRowBuilder();
 db_MGDataSet.MünzenRow f = new db_MGDataSet.MünzenRow(drb);`

But, the `DataRowBuilder` class is sealed and this class does not have a constructor. This this is also created by the entity model automatically, I think.

Comment: This is code generated when you create typed datasets! Entity Framework has nothing to do with this, which makes your question utterly confusing. I guess that the `MünzenRow` must first be created by a similar method in the Münzen typed dataset.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, thanks for your comment and sorry for any confusion, I didn't know any better. I will check your hint and come back to this.

Comment: I can't create 'MünzenRow', because the constructor needs a 'DataRowBuilder' object, but the 'DataRowBuilder' class does not have a constructor and the the 'DataRowBuilder' class is sealed.

Comment: Finally, i've got it :-)

Here is the solution:

`db_MGDataSet.MünzenDataTable münzenDataTable = new db_MGDataSet.MünzenDataTable();
db_MGDataSet.MünzenRow münzenRow = münzenDataTable.NewMünzenRow();
münzenRow.id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxMünzen.SelectedValue);
            db_MGDataSet.MünzenEinwerfen.AddMünzenEinwerfenRow(dateTimePickerDatum.Value, münzenRow, Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxAnzahl.SelectedItem));`

And it makes sense for me now and it is obviously related with the strongly typed data set.